# Como instanciar un objeto de una clase cuyo constructor tiene parámetros en java

Tags: java, arraylist, diseño-de-clases

Me estoy volviendo loco.

tengo una clase Persona:

```
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int edad;

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

Y tengo una clase estudiante que extiende de persona

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    private String codEstudiante;
    private int notaFinal;
 
    public Estudiante(String nombre, String apellidos, int edad, String codEstudiante, int notaFinal) {
        super(nombre, apellidos, edad);
        this.codEstudiante = codEstudiante;
        this.notaFinal = notaFinal;
    }

    public String getCodEstudiante() {
        return codEstudiante;
    }

    public int getNotaFinal() {
        return notaFinal;
    }

    public void setCodEstudiante(String codEstudiante) {
        this.codEstudiante = codEstudiante;
    }

    public void setNotaFinal(int notaFinal) {
        this.notaFinal = notaFinal;
    }

    public void metodoMostrarEsdutidantes(){
        System.out.println("Nombre " + getNombre() +
            "\nApellidos: " + getApellidos() +
            "\nEdad: " + getEdad() +
            "\nCódigo Estudiante: " + getCodEstudiante() +
            "\nNota Final: " + getNotaFinal());
    }
}
```

Alguien me podría indicar como puedo hacer funconar éste método que debería de grabar los datos en el arrayList ?

```
public static void metodoRecogerDatos(){
    
    System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del Estudiante: ");
    String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escroba los Apellidos: ");
    String apellidos = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Cual es la edad del estudiante: ");
    int edad = teclado.nextInt();
    teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Su código de Estudiante es: ");
    String codigoEstudiante = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del EstudianteNota Final obtenida: ");
    int notaFinal = teclado.nextInt();
    teclado.nextLine();
    
    //Estudiantes.add();
    //lo estoy haciendo así, pero al llamar al método que imprime los datos, me da el valor null
    Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, apellidos, edad, codigoEstudiante, notaFinal);
}
```

Alguien me puede decir como puedo llamar a al método metodoMostrarEsdutidantes() desde la clase principal ?

Cuando intento instanciar un objeto de la clase estudiante, me da error, y me dice que faltan los parámetros del constructor de la clase, así que por defecto le dí a la opción que me da netBeans para coerregirlo, y me ha agregado un constructor vacío, pero no se si será lo correcto

Mi clase principal es ésta:

```
public class Principal {
    ArrayList<Estudiante> Estudiantes = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int opcion = 0;
        do{
            opcion = metodoMostrarMenu();
            switch (opcion){
                case 1:
                    metodoRecogerDatos();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    metodoMostrarDatos();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);
    
    }
    public static void metodoRecogerDatos(){
    
        System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del Estudiante: ");
        String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escroba los Apellidos: ");
        String apellidos = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Cual es la edad del estudiante: ");
        int edad = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Su código de Estudiante es: ");
        String codigoEstudiante = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del EstudianteNota Final obtenida: ");
        int notaFinal = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
    
        //Estudiantes.add()
        Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, apellidos, edad, codigoEstudiante, notaFinal);
    }
    public static int metodoMostrarMenu(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Que función desea realizar");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 - Introducir estudiantes");
        System.out.println("2 - Ver Estudiantes");
        System.out.println("3 - Cerrar");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Su opción es: ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        int opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        return opcion;
    }

    private static void metodoMostrarDatos() {
        Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante();
        System.out.println("Los estudiantes matriculados son: ");
        miEstudiante.metodoMostrarEsdutidantes();
    }
}
```

El caso es que el código no da ningún error, pero al ejecutar el programa y meter los datos, al imprimirlo, sale todo null

Estoy muy perdido. Agradecería información. Gracias

Comment: Buenas, ¿has probado a crear el estudiante sólo cuando ya tienes los datos por teclado? Creo que te sobra esto: "Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante();", porque realmente lo que estás haciendo es hacer 2 new y sólo al primero le insertas datos y cuando los quieras recuperar no hagas un new, sólo tienes que acceder a la posición del array "Estudiantes.get(i)".

Comment: @FranCámara Tiene razón, esa línea (la 4ª, en el código de la pregunta, sobra)

Comment: Uff, a ver si me aclaro, voy a probar, gracias

Comment: Mira la respuesta que acabo de añadir, la explicación está al final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

en tu clase principal veo algunas cosas que no tienen sentido, deberías tener algo así:

```
public class Principal {
    private static ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiantes = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();
    private static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int opcion = 0;

        do{
            opcion = metodoMostrarMenu();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    metodoRecogerDatos();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    metodoMostrarDatos();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);
    }

    public static void metodoRecogerDatos() {
        System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del Estudiante: ");
        String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escroba los Apellidos: ");
        String apellidos = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Cual es la edad del estudiante: ");
        int edad = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Su código de Estudiante es: ");
        String codigoEstudiante = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escroba el nombre del EstudianteNota Final obtenida: ");
        int notaFinal = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();

        Estudiante miEstudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, apellidos, edad, codigoEstudiante, notaFinal);
        estudiantes.add(miEstudiante);
    }

    public static int metodoMostrarMenu() {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Que función desea realizar");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 - Introducir estudiantes");
        System.out.println("2 - Ver Estudiantes");
        System.out.println("3 - Cerrar");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Su opción es: ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        int opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        return opcion;
    }

    private static void metodoMostrarDatos() {
        System.out.println("Los estudiantes matriculados son: ");

        for (Estudiante estudiante : estudiantes) {
            estudiante.metodoMostrarEsdutidantes();
        }
    }
}
```

La explicación es sencilla, creas un estudiante con los datos que se insertan, lo añades a la lista y posteriormente la recorres recuperando los objetos y mostrándolos en función de la posición que ocupan en la lista.

Comment: Jope, pues si que soy inútil, menos mal que os tengo ahí. Muchísimas gracias, cambiada mi clase principal por la que has puesto, funciona a la perfección. Graciasssss

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos, nadie nació sabiendo.

Comment: @FranCámara justos estaba escribiendo la misma respuesta, solo hay una pequeña observación, la variable  de clase ``estudiantes `` tiene que ser static porque se está llamando desde un método ``static``

Comment: Cierto, de eso no me he dado cuenta.